# Por no termina de cargar form?

Tags: windows-forms, formularios, depuración, xdebug, bug

veran tengo una condicional, que cuando se cumple se tiene que abrir otro form, pero al momento de que la condicion se cumple y se abre el otro form se queda "cargando", hay otra condicion mas abajo, cuando se cumple esa, ahi si carga normalmente.. cabe aclarar que estas 2 condiciones suceden dentro de un evento de System Watcher, el llamado del form ocurre al final del primer IF

```
 public void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            ConversionKgtoGSaco = ConversionKgtoGSaco - PesoDeToner;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\2921095\Desktop\SuperSacosUsados\" + IDSuperSaco + ".txt", ConversionKgtoGSaco.ToString());
            conteoPesoToner = conteoPesoToner + PesoDeToner;
            ConteoDeBotes++;
            lblGramos.Text = ConteoDeBotes.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        catch(Exception d)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(d.Message);
        }
        if (ConteoDeBotes >= TamañoDeOrden)
        {
           
            TamañoDeOrden = 1;
            ConteoDeBotes = 0;
            
            txtbBuscarSuperSacoUsado.Enabled = true;
            txtIdSuperSaco.Enabled = true;
            txtNumeroDeProducto.Enabled = true;
            txtPesoSuperSaco.Enabled = true;
            txtTamañoDeOrden.Enabled = true;
            btnBuscarSacoUsado.Enabled = true;
            btnIniciarProceso.Enabled = true;
            checkBox1.Enabled = true;
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            txtbBuscarSuperSacoUsado.Text = "";
            //txtIdSuperSaco.Text = "";
            txtNumeroDeProducto.Text = "";
            //txtPesoSuperSaco.Text = "";
            txtTamañoDeOrden.Text = "";
            txtPesoSuperSaco.Text = ConversionKgtoGSaco.ToString();
            //Thread.Sleep(130);
            this.Hide();
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }
       
        if (conteoPesoToner > ConversionKgtoGSaco)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            TamañoDeSuperSaco = 0;
            ConversionKgtoGSaco = 0;
            txtIdSuperSaco.Text = "";
            txtPesoSuperSaco.Text = "0";
            txtIdSuperSaco.Enabled = true;
            txtPesoSuperSaco.Enabled = true;
            btnIniciarProceso.Enabled = true;
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Saco vacio");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Prueba a poner `this.Hide()` luego de `frm.Show()`

Comment: No funciono, aun estoy buscando una solucion